# How can I edit this redirect function to exclude my wordpress login page?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have a function that redirects my website visitors in Ireland and the UK to local versions of my website. My problem is the function redirects me too (I'm in Ireland) so I can't log in to edit my website if I use the function.
Can you please help me to exclude a couple of pages such as my WordPress login page?

```js
function country_geo_redirect() {
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
   return;
}

$country = getenv('HTTP_GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE');
if ( $country == "GB" ) {
wp_redirect( 'https://www.website.ie', 301 );
exit;
} else if ( $country == "IE" ) {
wp_redirect( 'https://www.website.co.uk', 301 );
exit;
}
}
add_action('init', 'country_geo_redirect');
```

Comment: Are you trying to edit the GB site but you're only able to access the IE one due to your location? I'm not sure I understand what you're asking

Answer (score 0):

You can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to save the preference in your browser that you don't want redirection.

localStorage is just one of the ways, you can also use a cookie for the same purpose.

This approach is more scalable then excluding certain pages.

```js
function country_geo_redirect() {
// Make sure that you set NO_REDIRECT to 1 in localStorage. `localStorage.setItem('NO_REDIRECT', '1')`
// localStorage persistence would ensure that no matter what countries you chose to redirect from or what countries you are accessing the website from, redirection won't occur as the persistence is in your browser.
if ( is_user_logged_in() || localStorage.getItem('NO_REDIRECT')=='1') {
   return;
}

$country = getenv('HTTP_GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE');
if ( $country == "GB" ) {
wp_redirect( 'https://www.website.ie', 301 );
exit;
} else if ( $country == "IE" ) {
wp_redirect( 'https://www.website.co.uk', 301 );
exit;
}
}
add_action('init', 'country_geo_redirect');
```

Comment: Thanks Hariom. Is it possible to edit the code to exclude a specific page? This would like different editors to continue accessing the site and allow me to continue working from different devices